# regex match text in between

Tags: javascript, regex

I get strings like:

```
"some text here /word/ asdhd"
"some other likehere/word1/hahas"
"some other likehere/dhsad huasdhuas huadssad/h ah as/"
```

What I need is to get the string between the two slashes, 'word', 'word1', 'dhsad huasdhuas huadssad' and 'h ah as'.

What is a regex for that?

Comment: can you have more than one in a given string?

Comment: and also, it always one single word with only word characters in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit in case you have **more** than one of those words and want to iterate through them.*
*Edit again since question was changed.*

```
var myregexp = /\/(.+?)(?=\/)/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {

        // matched text: match[1]

    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

**Explanation :**

```
    // \/(.+?)(?=\/)
// 
// Match the character “/” literally «\/»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.+?)»
//    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+?»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
// Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=\/)»
//    Match the character “/” literally «\/»
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "some other likehere/dhsad huasdhuas huadssad/h ah as/";
var matches = string.match(/[/](.*)[/]/)[1];
```

That should do it.

#### EDIT revised to match new criteria.

Comment: @myself not a problem XD I upvoted FailedDev's answer because I thought it was better too. :P  I'll leave my answer as a * possible* alternative to future visitors.

Comment: Im using your solution, I marked him as awnser because the explication can help other stackoverflow members. Anyway, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/
```

\/ matches slashes
[a-zA-Z0-9] matches any letters uppercase or lower, and any numbers
+ means one or more

Answer (score 0):

```
"some text here /word/ asdhd".match(/\/(.+)\//)
```

If you want to match more than one occurence in the same string, you need to use `exec`. See [@FailedDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096340/regex-match-text-in-between/8096386#8096386).

Comment: that breaks if there's more than one in a string :(

Comment: Make it lazy and it would work with several groups of `/ /` if you also set the global flag.

Comment: nvm... the OP changed the criteria.